# Получить массив дубликатов

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторый массив объектов. Необходимо получить новый массив состоящий только из дубликатов массива-исходника по конкретному свойству объекта.

**Пример**

Массив:

```
[{car: 'volga'},
 {car: 'lada'},
 {car: 'volga'},
 {car: 'volga'}]
```

Стало:

```
[{car: 'volga'},
 {car: 'volga'},
 {car: 'volga'}]
```

---

Сейчас делаю так (необходимо найти дубли по свойству account), но если объектов скажем 100к, то весь этот процесс выполняется довольно долго, вероятно есть решения лучше и быстрее. Прошу подсказать) Спасибо!

```
    const items = [{
      oid: 1,
      account: 'price003',
      category: 'FACT',
    },
    {
      oid: 2,
      account: 'price004',
      category: 'FACT',
    },
    {
      oid: 3,
      account: 'price003',
      category: 'FACT',
    },
    {
      oid: 4,
      account: 'price004',
      category: 'FACT',
    },
    {
      oid: 5,
      account: 'price04',
      category: 'FACT',
    }]
    
    let nonUniqItems = []
    
    for (let i of items) {
        for (let k of items) {
            if (i.account == k.account && i.oid !== k.oid) {
                if (!nonUniqItems.find(item => item.oid == i.oid)) nonUniqItems.push(i)
            }
        }
    }

console.log(nonUniqItems)
```

Comment: То есть, вам, фактически, надо исключить из исходного массива все те единственные элементы с уникальным относительно остальных значением `account`? Или все-таки отобрать все элементы с определенным значением `account`, переданным, скажем, в функцию?

Comment: @artomich Да, необходимо исключить элементы с уникальным относительно остальных значением account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл for...of сам по себе медленнее какого-нибудь forEach. Если нужна скорость, в первую очередь стоит избавиться от него.

```js
const items = [
  { oid: 1, account: 'price003', category: 'FACT' },
  { oid: 2, account: 'price004', category: 'FACT' },
  { oid: 3, account: 'price003', category: 'FACT' },
  { oid: 4, account: 'price004', category: 'FACT' },
  { oid: 5, account: 'price04', category: 'FACT' }
];

let accs = items.map(item => item.account);
// Отдельно собрать все значения .account
// ['price003', 'price004', ...'price04'];

let nonUniqItems = items.filter((item, i) => {
  return accs.indexOf(item.account) != i || accs.lastIndexOf(item.account) != i;
  // Если и слева, и справа, индекс совпадает с текущим, значит он один единственный.
});

console.log(nonUniqItems);
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @FerretBlack попробовал еще тупо посчитать количество всех значений, сохраняя их количество в объект, потом одним проходом отфильтровать только те, у которых число больше 1. Удивился, но текущий вариант всё равно быстрее)