# оставить в массиве объектов только те объекты у которых одинаковый title(JS)

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

есть объект:

```
let obj = [
{'title':4, 'content':'world'}
{'title':1, 'content':'hello'},
{'title':1, 'content':'bye'}, 
{'title':2, 'content':'world'},
{'title':3, 'content':'world'}
];
```

нужно оставить в массиве только те объекты которые имеют одинаковый title.

то есть должно получиться:

```
let obj = [
{'title':1, 'content':'hello'},
{'title':1, 'content':'bye'}, 
];
```

Comment: То есть только те объекты, title которых встречается более одного раза?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить массив дубликатов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149608/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2) - То же самое, там account - тут title)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял условия , в голову приходят два способа. Первый на вид проще, но не такой эффективный (совершается много частичных проходов по массиву). Второй чуть сложнее, с промежуточной структурой данных, но должен быть эффективнее, потому что массив перебирается всего два раза.

```js
const obj = [
  {'title':4, 'content':'world'},
  {'title':1, 'content':'hello'},
  {'title':1, 'content':'bye'},
  {'title':2, 'content':'world'},
  {'title':3, 'content':'world'}
];

// Way 1.

const filtered1 = obj.filter(
  (entry1, index1) => obj.some((entry2, index2) =>
    entry1.title === entry2.title && index1 !== index2)
);

console.log(filtered1);

// Way 2.

const titleNum = obj.reduce(
  (acc, entry) => {
    const { title } = entry;
    if (acc[title] === undefined) acc[title] = 0;
    acc[title]++;
    return acc;
  }, {}
);

const filtered2 = obj.filter(({ title }) => titleNum[title] > 1);

console.log(filtered2);
```